# Google search with tbm=map downloads something

Tags: google-search

I was learning about making HTML form which will start Google search on submit and I found out something. When you put `tbm=map` in the search URL, it downloads something which looks like JSON data.

Example URLs:
https://www.google.com/search?q=abc&tbm=map
https://gist.github.com/ZaifSenpai/7a7abc2cefc08b3e793de00cc605221b

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What is the question? Ref. [ask] Please bear in mind that this site is for questions about **using** web apps. Related: [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, remove the junk on the first line and remove the last quote and you've got access to a google maps place record in json format!

```
content=re.sub(r'^.{0,10}\[\[','[[',content)  #remove start
content=re.sub(r'\'$','',content)  #remove end quote
record=json.loads(content)
```